# A question about Inverse Matrix

Tags: inverse, matrix-equations

I have a question about Inverse Matrix. I would appreciate if anyone could provide some help.

> Question:
>
> Suppose that a matrix A satisfies the equation $A^2-4A+3I=0$.  Find an
> expression for $A^-1$.

When I working on this question

> $A^2-4A=-3I$
>
> $(-1/3)(A^2-4A)=I$
>
> $(-1/3)A(A-4I)=I$

I don't understand why $A^2-4A$ become $A(A-4I)$

Then I saw my teacher wrote this:

> 4*I is a matrix and 4 is a number so they aren't the same, but 4A =
> 4AI = A(4I)
>
> so A2−4A=A.A−A.4I=A(A−4I)

As I know $AA^-1=I$, if $A(A-4I)$ put back the A inside the (),

it will become $A^2-4AI$ -> $A^2-4AAA^-1$

It’s blowing my mind. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have fixed it ^^

Answer (score 1):

That $A^2-4A = A(A-4I)$ is just laws of matrix multiplication. You can really just prove the law $A(B+C)=AB+AC$ for all matrices s.t. the dimensions fit if you wish to.